# How to display a splashscreen on iphone/android?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile, splash-screen

I have a website which also provides a mobile application (iphone/android).

I'd like to set up a splashscreen whenever an user connects to the website :

- Set a cookie to show the splashscreen once every week (for example)
- I'd like the image takes the fullscreen of the mobile while keeping the ratio.

Any ideas/tools/advices ?

Should it be server side or client side? (I'm using jQuery/PHP/Zend Framework)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what I've done in the past is using a JavaScript confirm which is styled beautifully on iPhones

for example:

```
if(cookie is not set and browser is iOS) 
{
    var where_to=confirm("We have launched an iPhone/iPod Touch App. Would you like to download it?");

    document.cookie = 'seen_iphone_prompt=1; expires= {{date here}}; path=/'

    if(where_to==true)
    {
        window.location="http://app_store.com?link=here;
    }
}
```

This method is good as it forces the user to take an action, where as a custom splash people could just hit close. Might need to add some cases in here for android but the principle is the same

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery Mobile to create the splashscreen. You have specific methods to get the screen width:

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

This splashscreen should be a link to your mobile app. 
Regarding the cookies, each cookie has an expiry date after which it is trashed. If you don't specify the expiry date the cookie is trashed when you close the browser. This expiry date should be in UTC (Greenwich) time.

```
document.cookie ='ppkcookie1=testcookie; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of the proper css being set up.

Give yourself an element after the body tag, not nested any further.

```
<body>
    <div id="splash"></div>
</body>
```

Set its css to:

```
#splash {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

If your body wraps beyond the page (meaning it needs to scroll), it might help to set the body to:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Awesome, you have a splash page! Just add your content in `#splash`.

Now, you have to show it every week...well i would personally opt to use localStorage over cookies, seeing how you are working in a mobile space that supports it. Here is a reference [link](http://playground.html5rocks.com/#localstorage).

To get an item:

```
localStorage.getItem( 'name_of_item' );
```

To set an item:

```
localStorage.setItem( 'name_of_item', 'some value that has to be a string' );
```

Once you pop the splash screen off, and if you have more content that needs to scroll, be sure to remove the `overflow:hidden` from the body.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This will add a Splash Screen to your Web App. Below are the sizes you’ll need for both iPad and iPhone/iPod Touch, these include the status bar area as well.

iPad Landscape – 1024 x 748

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x748" href="img/splash-screen-1024x748.png" />
```

iPad Portrait – 768 x 1004

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="img/splash-screen-768x1004.png" />
```

iPhone/iPod Touch Portrait – 320 x 480 (standard resolution)

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/splash-screen-320x460.png" />
```

iPhone/iPod Touch Portrait – 640 x 960 pixels (Retina Display high-resolution)

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x960" href="img/splash-screen-640x960.png" />
```

If creating a Web App for iPad compatibility it’s recommended that both Landscape and Portrait sizes are used.